# square root of a symetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I have a symmetric matrix which positive-definite, but it contains zero as eigen value. So the method of Cholesky does not work, could someone give another method to do this? I do not want an iteration method, just as Denman–Beavers iteration and Babylonian method to the exact square root of a given matrix. Many thanks!

Comment: If it possesses zero eigenvalues, it is, by definition, *not* positive definite. Also, can you simply diagonalise $A=U\Sigma U^\ast$ and take $\sqrt{A}$ as $U\sqrt{\Sigma}U^\ast$?

Comment: the general diagonalisation is not very fast in computer, is there any better method

Comment: @user1551 Orthogonal diagonalization is an iterative method (usually done by an iterative repetition of the QR factorization).

Comment: @VedranŠego I know (see my answer), but when I wrote my comment, I thought the OP meant to find the square root by hand (with the aid of an interactive environment such as Matlab).

Comment: @user84572, a decent $A=LDL^T$ decomposition should be fast on your computer (i.e. similar to Cholesky). E.g. check out http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Answer (score 2):

You may read chapters 6 (Matrix Square Root) and 7 (Matrix $p$th Root) of Higham's *[Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=S6gpNn1JmbgC&pg=PA1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)* to see if there is anything helpful. However, practically all linear algebra solvers are iterative in nature. If you want something non-iterative, I doubt there is any.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use the square root's Taylor series (calculating only the sum of the first few elements):
$$\sqrt{{\rm I} + X} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(1-2n)(n!)^2(4^n)}X^n = {\rm I} + \frac{1}{2}X - \frac{1}{8} X^2 + \frac{1}{16} X^3 - \frac{5}{128} X^4 + \dots$$
However, just because you could, doesn't mean you should, as this is a very bad approach (slow, numerically unstable,...). There are good reasons why this stuff is done iteratively.

If your positive **semi**definite matrix is of an order up to $4$, you might be able to get an exact formula for the elements of its square root. Otherwise, forget the non-iterative methods and follow @user1551's advice on reading Higham's book.